# How to get p2 to consider an update to a feature & plugin?

Tags: equinox, p2

I've got version 1.1.0 of a feature installed [image: currently installed listing 1.1.0] that I've deployed a version 1.1.1 of, as visible in the 'Install new software' view: [image: install new software view listing 1.1.1].

However, 'Check for software updates' is saying there are no updates available. Why is this?

Comment: You say that you have the "Smart Constraint" feature installed, but the screen shot shows a "Smart Constratin" plug-in. So what do you have installed? Or do you have both installed?

Comment: I wasn't sure, but checking the 'Features' list does not reveal it - so perhaps I don't have the feature installed.

Answer (score 0):

'Check for updates' will only check for updates on the installation seeds. These are the features and the product that is listed on the 'Installed Software' tab in the installation details.

'Check for updates' will not check the dependencies of the installation seeds for new versions. So in your case, it seems that the "Smart Constraint" feature is not installed as seed but only as dependency of one of the other seeds.

To get the new version installed, you can simply install it via the 'Install new software' dialog. This will install the new version (possibly requiring other updates to mitigate conflicting dependencies), and make the feature a seed so that it will be updated by a 'Check for updates' in the future.

Comment: Hmm, nothing depends on Smart Constraint - I install it directly using 'Install new software'. Confusingly though, while it appears in the Plug-ins category, it does not appear in the Features tab.

Comment: I'm not sure why, because it is installed in the features/ folder of the installation.